# Is Spring Boot multipartfile not modifiable?

Tags: java, spring, request

I have an issue that I want to change the MultipartFile of one request as I have to get the uploaded file decrypt before my service can use it as a normal excel file or some other format. To do this, I write a `CustomerMultipartFile` class implements `MultipartFile`, and put the decrypt bytes into the new class, and use it as a `MultipartFile` instance. But I find that when I use the bytes of the modified request file, the bytes array is completely different from what I set into  it. Here is the code :

```
        registry.addInterceptor(new HandlerInterceptorAdapter() {
        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
                throws Exception {

            boolean isMultipart = multipartResolver.isMultipart(request);

            if(isMultipart && encrypt.isEncrypt()){
                Map<String, MultipartFile> map =  multipartResolver.resolveMultipart(request).getFileMap();

                Set<String> keys = map.keySet();

                for(String key : keys){
                    MultipartFile file = map.get(key);

                    byte[] content = FileUtils.decrypt(file.getBytes());

                    CustomerMultipartFile cf = new CustomerMultipartFile();
                    cf.setContentType(file.getContentType());
                    cf.setName(file.getName());
                    cf.setOriginalFilename(file.getOriginalFilename());

                    cf.setBytes(content);
                    cf.setSize(content.length);


                    map.put(key, cf);
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Any attempt is appreciated.